# How to add dynamic dataset using chart.js in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, charts, chart.js, pie-chart

I'm trying to display one pie chart for each question from my database. Right now, I am only able to display one chart on the first question.

I don't know how to display charts for the rest of the questions. I'm also not sure if I'm doing it the right way? I'm currently using ViewBag to pass the data from controller. How do I do it properly?

Please help me. Thanks.

This is my View:

```
<table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Questions
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var question in (List<Testv3.Models.MyViewModel>)ViewData["questionlist"])
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @question.Question
                                <br />
                                <div class="chart">
                                    <canvas id="pie-chart"></canvas>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
</table>

@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">

    var PieChartData =
        {
            labels: ["Agree", "Somewhat Agree", "Disagree"],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Overall report',
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#f990a7",
                    "#aad2ed",
                    "#9966FF",
                ],
                borderWidth: 2,
                data: [@ViewBag.countAgree, @ViewBag.countSomewhatAgree, @ViewBag.countDisagree]
            }]
        };

        window.onload = function () {
            var ctx1 = document.getElementById("pie-chart").getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx1,
                {
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: PieChartData,
                    options:
                        {
                            responsive: true,
                            maintainAspectRatio: true
                        }
                });
        }

</script>
```

This is my controller:

```
            List<PsychTestViewModel> questionlist = new List<PsychTestViewModel>();
            var datalistQuestions = db.Questions.ToList();

            foreach (var question in datalistQuestions)
            {
                PsychTestViewModel ptvm = new PsychTestViewModel();
                ptvm.QuestionID = question.QuestionID;
                ptvm.Question = question.Question;
                questionlist.Add(ptvm);

                ViewBag.questionlist = questionlist;

                var agree = from ans in db.Answers
                            where ans.Answer == 1 && ans.QuestionID == ptvm.QuestionID
                            select new { Answer = ans.Answer };


                var somewhatAgree = from ans in db.Answers
                                    where ans.Answer == 2 && ans.QuestionID == ptvm.QuestionID
                                    select new { Answer = ans.Answer };


                var disagree = from ans in db.Answers
                               where ans.Answer == 3 && ans.QuestionID == ptvm.QuestionID
                               select new { Answer = ans.Answer };

                int Agree = agree.Count();
                int SomewhatAgree = somewhatAgree.Count();
                int Disagree = disagree.Count();

                ViewBag.countSomewhatAgree = SomewhatAgree;
                ViewBag.countAgree = Agree;
                ViewBag.countDisagree = Disagree;
            }
```

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html (you have `<canvas id="pie-chart">` inside a loop) and `document.getElementById("pie-chart")` will only ever return the first element with that `id`

Comment: And you controller code is just overwriting your `ViewBag` properties in each iteration. You need to return a collection of a model containing 3 properties (for `agree`, `somewhatAgree` and `disagree`